# How to locate all the fields where an specific data is?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to do a groups system. The structure in firebase is like this:

**Groups (collection)-> GroupsUID(doc) -> data**

Here is an image from the cloud store firebase:

[The user UID in a group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnHwF.png)

[The same user UID in a different group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH2Vg.png)

In the data is an array of members, which have all the UID's of all the individual users that are in the group. How can I get all the groups that a specific user is?, in other words, how can I get all the groups UID's where an specific user is?. In the example of the images it should return two Groups UID's, which are: "w04YzgnA92dn9kuzHAhe" and "ipm5WrAMVJG5CZSPGdDP", it could be more Groups UID's, but I only want to get all the Groups UID's where certain user is.

I've already tried this:

```
class Database {
  final String uid;
  
  Database(this.uid); //Gets the UID when is initialized (Example uid =
IPTIQ0In0kMjKb9GZF4Ap11N32x2 )

  final CollectionReference newGroupReminder = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Groups');

  Future<void> getListGroup(List<Group> litems) async {
    await newGroupReminder
        .where('arrayMembers', arrayContains: this.uid) // Look up for the user UID
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc.data()['groupName']);
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to: 1) show the value of `UserUID` that you test with? 2) Show a screenshot of a document you'd expect to get back for that value (in addition to the structure you already have)?

Comment: I want to help you but your question is bit unclear , can you please modify it in a better way ?

Comment: Are there any security rules which restrict read access?

Comment: Also, from the screenshots, it seems that there is a space at the end of the UID value in the array =>  "IPTIQ0In0kMjKb9GZF4Ap11N32x2 " (see the space after the 2)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec this are the rules:                                                                   `rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: So, is your user authenticated? Because with `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;` only authenticated users can read. You can try with `allow read, write: if true;`to see if this is the problem (of course do that only in a dev environment, not in prod!)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec It was actually that blank space right there, thank you very much for all the help